# Split array into multi sub arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

i have a multi array with several indices and i need to be able to split the array into multiple array with 2 indexes, my code is below

The query returns an array i then loop thought it to make it a multi array then take specific indices and rebuild the array but when i tried to split the final result into smaller arrays with array chunk it simple returns the same array.

```
$query = DB::Table('StockHistory')
             ->select('price_1','day_1','price_2','day_2','price_3','day_3','price_4','day_4','price_5','day_5')
             ->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
         $fields = [];
         foreach($query as $ind => $val) {
             foreach($val as $x => $y){
                 $fields[] =  [$x, $y];
             }
         }
         $data = [ $fields ];
         $output = array_map(function($value) {
             return [ $value[1][1],
                      $value[0][1],
                      $value[3][1],
                      $value[4][1],
                      $value[5][1],
                      $value[6][1]];
         }, $data);
         $a = array_chunk($output, 2, false);
```

returned array by $output

```
 array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      0 => "2016-01-06"
      1 => 10
      2 => "2016-01-12"
      3 => 16
      4 => "2016-01-18"
      5 => 17
    ]
  ]
]
```

Desired array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:6 [▼
      0 => "2016-01-06"
      1 => 10
    1 => array:2[▼
      0 => "2016-01-12"
      1 => 16
    2 => array:2[▼
      0 => "2016-01-18"
      1 => 17
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this

```
<?php $a=array_chunk($output[0][0], 2, false); ?>
```